# Loop through nested objects

Tags: javascript

[image]

I have three functions, one provides the website info, the second shows the different sub apps within that website and the third shows the count of how many sub apps each website has. How would I loop through this so that I can append the sub funcion items to each website while sub_id is less than or equal to the sub_count for each ID. Note there can be more than one ID in all tables. I also need to be able to use the outermost value (WEB) inside the inner most nested function.

Started Coding Below, but Im not sure if I nested COUNT properly:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Controller/WEB",
    type: "post",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result, status) {
        $.each(result, function () {
            if (this.has_Sub == "True")
            {
                var _id = this.ID
                $.getJSON("/Controller/COUNT", function (result) {
                    $.each(result, function () {
                        if (this.ID == _id) {                    
                        }
                    });
                });
             }
        });
});
```

Comment: Are they `objects` or `functions` ?

Comment: sorry they are objects

Comment: Why not retrieve what you want with the initial AJAX request?

Comment: I will handle code differently when Has_Sub is False

Comment: Add more code to the post including the objects that you are referring and the expected output